Definite article or zero article in [noun] of [noun] phrase
I think that in the noun of noun phrases, we should use a definite article in front of them to show they are specific, but I quickly found some exceptions:

Details of the plan soon leaked out.
Details of the accident are scarce.
Results of the research testing will be shared with the participants

So what are the differences between using definite artilces or not in the above sentences? what are the reasons of omitting definite articles?

"Details" and "results" can both be used as non-count nouns. For example, you could refer to "some details",  "all of the details".
So, your examples are fine as they are, but they don't specify if the details/results will be complete. Adding the definite article would make them sound complete (ie all of the details/results).

I don't think (2) would work with the definite article, because if details are scarce we obviously don't have 'all of the details'.
